# Projectile motion, what is the relation between initial angle and speed at a given distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile, kinematics

I am trying to understand the relation between the initial angle of a projectile and its initial speed, given that the distance this projectile will travel is fixed and at the same height as the origin.

So far, I've used the equations of motion in two dimensions, combining $D=v_{i}^{x}\times t$ with $t_{max}=\frac{|\vec{v_{i}}|}{g}\times \sin\theta$ to get:
$$D=|\vec{v_{i}}|\times \cos\theta \times 2 \times \frac{|\vec{v_{i}}|}{g}\times \sin\theta$$ which I then simplify to:
$$g\times D = \sin2\theta\times|\vec{v_{i}}|^2$$

I'm aware this can also be seen as just a mathematical question, but I'm trying to understand the relation between the angle and the speed, and I just can't get passed this point.

Comment: The relation between the initial angle and speed is $ gD = v_0^2 \sin 2\theta_0 $, as you derived. What are you hung up on? Are you trying to solve for $v_0$?

Comment: I fail to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry for my being unclear. I was trying to ask the question, and also explain the ground work I had done thus far. But the answer below actually explained it pretty well plotting it to see the relation between the angle and the velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help feeling there's more to this than meets the eye, but taking your question at face value a quick rearrangement of your equation gives:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{gD}{\sin 2\theta}} $$

A quick graph (for D = 100m) looks like:

[image: Velocity-Angle]

As you'd expect, the required velocity goes to infinity for $\theta = 0$ and $\pi/2$, and it's a minimum at an angle of $\pi/4$.